# PHP: Hide/show element when visitors visit certain page

Tags: php

I construct my webpages like this:

```
<?php
   include ('header.html');

?>

<p> bla bla bla </p>

<?php

include ('footer.html');

?>
```

I use session in the header.html to track the user records. The header.html has got three  tags, called logo on the left, search_form in the middle, and login/ sign up buttons on the right

Now, the question is that I would like to hide the search_form DIV in the middle by using php in the header.html file if and when the internet users (not registered members) visit the certain page, e.g., register.php, because this DIV is not necessary.

Note: I would like to control it using PHP, but not javascript or anything else.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Set a boolean flag in the header-file, or store it in the session, and use that for an `if` around your div.

Comment: it should be a php page not html @dognose

Answer (score 0):

Change your `header.html` page to `header.php`.

in `header.php` check that if  current user as a registered user then show the search div  or 
check current page by your browser url and make decision whether you want to show search div or not.

You can use session to get current user information in `header.php`

sample code:

header.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['current_user'])){ //check register user
 // show div
}
else {
 $page= $_REQUEST['current_url']; // get current page
 if($page == 'register.php' || $page == 'whatever' ){ //check pages where you are not show search page
   echo '';
  }
  else {

  //show div
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried yours and this one: if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'register.php')){
  echo ' ';
}else{ // show DIV}. But it does not work. any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to check if the current url is, for example, 'register.php'. Something like:

```
<? php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'mysite.com/register.php'):
        include ('register_form.php');
?>
```

Of course, this would only work if the url matched exactly, and query strings would break this. But you get the general idea.

Look into creating sessions and user authentication using PHP.

Comment: This does not work as I tried. I also tried building $_SESSION['view']= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; then I use if(isset($_SESSION['view']) == 'mysite.com/register.php') { echo 'something';} . However, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['view'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['view']) && $_SESSION['view'] == '/test/index.php') {
    ?>
    <div>head</div>
    <?php } ?>
    body here
    <div>footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my sample work and this is works correctly. If my url not equal to /test/index.php it does not show head. You can set your own logic according to this demo work. I think it can help you.

Comment: it works. However, when I browse other pages beside this register.php, it's also hidden. I guess the problem is still at $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tried and found out the solution already. Now, I can share it with you guys:

```
if( (isset($_SESSION['current_user'])) || (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != 'register.php') ){

//  show the search_form DIV 

}
```

Thanks for your contribution!